# After upgrading springboot to Version 3.2.1 maven surefire plugin error is shown only in Jenkins

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

After upgrading springboot to 3.2.1 maven surefire plugin error is shown only in Jenkins. On local everything is passing.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.1.2:verify (default)

Has anyone faced this issue? appreciate any help on this.
Thanks.